# Set up PayPal with wrong email by mistake

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, paypal

I set up a PayPal in WooCom and the email that I typed in was in error.  Just found this out when someone placed an order and it was placed ON HOLD. So, I have a client that paid for her order, but no way to have it get into my clients PayPal account.  I also can't refund it. It is just frozen.

Comment: I think you need to talk to PayPal support and explain the situation. I'm not sure what we can do to help, sorry.

Comment: That said, I don't think you can actually do this. [Setting up PayPal integration](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/paypal-express-checkout/#section-4) requires API details that you wouldn't have unless you could actually log into the PayPal account. And I'd be surprised if you could do that without verifying the email address. On the off chance you do have these API keys it might be possible to call the API yourself and process the refund that way though.

Comment: PayPal was able to sort it out so the payments went thru to my client.  And yes, you can set up an API key and mistype in the email address and screw it all up, I have proof. :}